# How to pass this rule with larastan?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

I am using Laravel 10 + larastan to inspect my code, at level 9 (maximum).

I have this error :

**Access to an undefined property App\Models\User::$full_name.**

The code is :

```
$model->created_by = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->full_name : '?';
```

And the User model has the property $full_name declared

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

/**
 * @property uuid $id
 * @property string $full_name
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
```

I tried of a things without success. So what could be my error ?

Comment: You have a higher chance of solving this problem if you ask on Larastan’s GitHub 